# Что контролирует сеть в Linaro linux?

Tags: linux, сеть

Имею образ Linaro linux под ARM, но не могу понять, что контролирует на нём сеть.
Пробовал останавливать networking и NetworkManager, но они никак не влияют на сеть, eth0 всегда получает ip и разрыва сети не происходит.
Если же задать какие-то настройки в /etc/network/interfaces, например, статический ip, то перезапуск тех служб также ничего не меняет.
Но если перезагрузить устройство целиком, то все прописанные сетевые настройки из файла будут применены.

Что может контролировать сеть в этом образе Linaro linux?
Как понять, какая служба может контролировать сеть?

Comment: если пока не снесли к монахам networkmanager, то именно он и конфигурирует интерфейс, причём, судя по описанному вами, делает это только при загрузке.  если интерфейс описан в `/etc/network/interfaces`, то nm обязан убрать от него свои грязные лапы и конфигурация происходит нормальными штатными debian-овскими средствами (см. `/etc/init.d/networking` и далее)

Comment: Да, спасибо, почитал, что написано в /etc/init.d/networking
И понял, что там делается просто ifdown eth0 или ifup eth0, чего мне и достаточно. Спасибо, сразу что-то не подумал про if{down,up} eth0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему-то, в этом образе вызывал проблему с сетью NetworkManager, его отключил.
А также мне подошло отключение и включение сетевого интерфейса через ifdown eth0 и ifup eth0.